# R: Error while expanding a JSON with dynamic cols and rows

Tags: r, json, dplyr

I have a problem when trying to expand a dataframe that contain two rows with a JSON string in a column. My intention is to expand the different layers into different new columns and rows on the dataframe.

```
#Reproducible csv:
json.csv <- r"("","object_name","response"
"1","B3 reflection","[{""question"":{""id"":46445,""text"":""What did you see in this module that you already do or have seen in other classrooms?"",""question_id"":1,""requirements"":{""answer_type"":""text"",""text_required"":true}},""response"":{""free_text"":{""id"":""46445_ft"",""text"":1}}},{""question"":{""id"":46446,""text"":""What do you feel is the gap between your current practice and what you have seen in this module?"",""question_id"":2,""requirements"":{""answer_type"":""text"",""text_required"":true}},""response"":{""free_text"":{""id"":""46446_ft"",""text"":1}}}]"
"2","B1 Reflection","[{""question"":{""id"":22061,""text"":""What did you see in this module that you already do or have seen in other classrooms?"",""question_id"":135,""requirements"":{""answer_type"":""text"",""text_required"":true}},""response"":{""free_text"":{""id"":""22061_ft"",""text"":""Strong classroom routines and high expectations""}}},{""question"":{""id"":22062,""text"":""What do you feel is the gap between your current practice and what you have seen in this module?"",""question_id"":136,""requirements"":{""answer_type"":""text"",""text_required"":true}},""response"":{""free_text"":{""id"":""22062_ft"",""text"":""Making sure I am consistent in classroom routines""}}},{""question"":{""id"":22063,""text"":""Which of the \u2018key takeaways\u2019 do you need to focus on? Where and when might you try to apply them to your teaching?"",""question_id"":137,""requirements"":{""answer_type"":""text"",""text_required"":true}},""response"":{""free_text"":{""id"":""22063_ft"",""text"":""Holding high ...""}}}]")"
```

Let's load the data using a text connection:

```
json_map = read.csv(text = json.csv)
```

I am using this code in `dplyr` to expand row wise the previous two rows from the dataframe and it works perfectly well when I expand every row individually and when I do that individually it works perfectly well for everyone of the two rows

```
#Already tried with these two and work perfectly fine
json_map = json_map[1,]
json_map = json_map[2,]


json_map = json_map |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(response = map(response, jsonlite::fromJSON)) |>
  unnest_longer(response) |>
  unnest_wider(c(response), names_sep = "_") |>
  unnest_wider(c(response_response, response_question), names_sep = "_") |> 
  unnest_longer(c(response_response_free_text, response_question_requirements))|>
  unnest_wider(response_response_free_text, names_sep = "_") |> 
  unnest_longer(response_question_requirements)|> 
  unnest_wider(response_question_requirements, names_sep = "_")
```

Now, when I try to expand with all the dataframe `json_map` at the same time, the operation returns this error:

```
Error in `col_to_long()`:
! Can't combine `..1$response$response$free_text$text` <integer> and `..3$response$response$free_text$text` <character>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

From my understanding the only difference in both is that the `$response$response$free_text$text` layer contains an integer instead a character, so I tried to add `mutate_all(as.character)` at the end expecting it would convert everything into strings but it returns the same exact error.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Your data is not reproducible, please update your question accordingly. An expected output is also benefical

Comment: The reproducible example requires to simply copy and paste the first code snippet into any text editor and save it as a csv. Because a JSON has double quotes in it,  and as you might know R does not like that, and, hence, I did not want to use the scape ```\"``` and change the original JSON, I explained a way to make a csv. I don't know what is not reproducible about it. Also, the expected output is implicit in the beginning of the explanation when I specifically say "My intention is to expand the different layers into different new columns and rows on the dataframe."

Comment: To enhance your chances of receiving assistance, it's advisable to make your data readily accessible rather than expecting Stack Overflow users to navigate through additional steps. As recommended in the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example), using `dput()` to share the relevant data and providing a table of expected output, as demonstrated in the article, is preferred.

Comment: Thanks @Hoel and I understand that, among other reasons because I'm not new in this community, but I think I have already explained the reasons why my question does not have a reproducible example the way you request it to be, which is specific to JSON outputs in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

json.csv <- r"("","object_name","response"
"1","B3 reflection","[{""question"":{""id"":46445,""text"":""What did you see in this module that you already do or have seen in other classrooms?"",""question_id"":1,""requirements"":{""answer_type"":""text"",""text_required"":true}},""response"":{""free_text"":{""id"":""46445_ft"",""text"":1}}},{""question"":{""id"":46446,""text"":""What do you feel is the gap between your current practice and what you have seen in this module?"",""question_id"":2,""requirements"":{""answer_type"":""text"",""text_required"":true}},""response"":{""free_text"":{""id"":""46446_ft"",""text"":1}}}]"
"2","B1 Reflection","[{""question"":{""id"":22061,""text"":""What did you see in this module that you already do or have seen in other classrooms?"",""question_id"":135,""requirements"":{""answer_type"":""text"",""text_required"":true}},""response"":{""free_text"":{""id"":""22061_ft"",""text"":""Strong classroom routines and high expectations""}}},{""question"":{""id"":22062,""text"":""What do you feel is the gap between your current practice and what you have seen in this module?"",""question_id"":136,""requirements"":{""answer_type"":""text"",""text_required"":true}},""response"":{""free_text"":{""id"":""22062_ft"",""text"":""Making sure I am consistent in classroom routines""}}},{""question"":{""id"":22063,""text"":""Which of the \u2018key takeaways\u2019 do you need to focus on? Where and when might you try to apply them to your teaching?"",""question_id"":137,""requirements"":{""answer_type"":""text"",""text_required"":true}},""response"":{""free_text"":{""id"":""22063_ft"",""text"":""Holding high ...""}}}]")"

json_map = read.csv(text = json.csv) %>% 
  as_tibble() 

json_map %>% 
  mutate(response = map(response, ~ fromJSON(.x) %>% 
                          unnest(everything()) %>% 
                          unnest(everything(), names_sep = "_") %>% 
                          mutate(across(everything(), as.character)))) %>% 
  unnest(response) %>%  
  type_convert() 

# A tibble: 5 × 9
      X object_name      id text             question_id requirements_answer_…¹ requirements_text_re…² free_text_id
  <int> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl> <chr>                  <lgl>                  <chr>       
1     1 B3 reflection 46445 What did you se…           1 text                   TRUE                   46445_ft    
2     1 B3 reflection 46446 What do you fee…           2 text                   TRUE                   46446_ft    
3     2 B1 Reflection 22061 What did you se…         135 text                   TRUE                   22061_ft    
4     2 B1 Reflection 22062 What do you fee…         136 text                   TRUE                   22062_ft    
5     2 B1 Reflection 22063 Which of the ‘k…         137 text                   TRUE                   22063_ft    
# ℹ abbreviated names: ¹​requirements_answer_type, ²​requirements_text_required
# ℹ 1 more variable: free_text_text <chr>
```

Reproduceble data from this:

```
dput(json_map)

structure(list(X = 1:2, object_name = c("B3 reflection", "B1 Reflection"
), response = c("[{\"question\":{\"id\":46445,\"text\":\"What did you see in this module that you already do or have seen in other classrooms?\",\"question_id\":1,\"requirements\":{\"answer_type\":\"text\",\"text_required\":true}},\"response\":{\"free_text\":{\"id\":\"46445_ft\",\"text\":1}}},{\"question\":{\"id\":46446,\"text\":\"What do you feel is the gap between your current practice and what you have seen in this module?\",\"question_id\":2,\"requirements\":{\"answer_type\":\"text\",\"text_required\":true}},\"response\":{\"free_text\":{\"id\":\"46446_ft\",\"text\":1}}}]", 
"[{\"question\":{\"id\":22061,\"text\":\"What did you see in this module that you already do or have seen in other classrooms?\",\"question_id\":135,\"requirements\":{\"answer_type\":\"text\",\"text_required\":true}},\"response\":{\"free_text\":{\"id\":\"22061_ft\",\"text\":\"Strong classroom routines and high expectations\"}}},{\"question\":{\"id\":22062,\"text\":\"What do you feel is the gap between your current practice and what you have seen in this module?\",\"question_id\":136,\"requirements\":{\"answer_type\":\"text\",\"text_required\":true}},\"response\":{\"free_text\":{\"id\":\"22062_ft\",\"text\":\"Making sure I am consistent in classroom routines\"}}},{\"question\":{\"id\":22063,\"text\":\"Which of the \\u2018key takeaways\\u2019 do you need to focus on? Where and when might you try to apply them to your teaching?\",\"question_id\":137,\"requirements\":{\"answer_type\":\"text\",\"text_required\":true}},\"response\":{\"free_text\":{\"id\":\"22063_ft\",\"text\":\"Holding high ...\"}}}]"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thanks @Hoel, I had to add a couple more lines duplicating the                           ```unnest(everything()) %>%  unnest(everything(), names_sep = "_") %>% ``` lines to every additional level to unfold completely but the logic worked fairly well. Very clean and clever addition using the ```everything()``` command instead of the column names. That, in fact, makes it more flexible to other cases that I needed something similar to this. Again, appreciate the support.